# How to remove the mapping from Ctrl-[ to Escape?

Tags: key-bindings, escape

> If you have an American English keyboard, pressing Ctrl-[ (control plus left square bracket) is equivalent to pressing Esc. This provides an easy way to exit from insert mode.

source: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key

So I just learned this after spending the last 3 months full time going nuts over why pressing escape double for me activated some function that I didn't want. Because obviously double escape should not be different from single escape.

So turns out I have the `Ctrl-[` key in use... Which turns out is something poisoned.

Yeah so I'm gonna keep myself civil and not ask why on earth this is a thing, but just kindly ask if there is a way to turn that "feature" off?

Comment: You can't remove it, because this is the way terminals work; the escape key *is* Control+[. I wrote a page with some explanation and history on it: https://bestasciitable.com/

Comment: That's because it is the same key, just another way of specifying. See also http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vim is a terminal based program and has its key handling from the terminal. Also the GUI variants still act like this (with a few extensions).

In a terminal `Ctrl-A` is ASCII `0x01`, `Ctrl-B` is ASCII `0x02` and so on.
`Ctrl-Z` is `0x1A` and `Ctrl-[` is `0x1B`.

And `0x1B` is also the ASCII code for `ESC`.

Vim can't differentiate between `ESC` and `Ctrl-[`, because it gets the same key code when either is pressed.

For the same reason it can't differentiate between `Ctrl-I` and `<TAB>`. Both produce `0x09`.