# Mapping <C-[> causes input() to not be abortable

Tags: key-bindings, user-input

The following function, when at the prompt, if one presses `<Esc>`, then it will print `EXIT`.

```
function! Testinput()
    let g:searchString = input("Enter search string: ", 'default', 'syntax')
    if g:searchString == '' || g:searchString == '\n'
        echom "EXIT"
    else
        echom "CONTINUIE"
    endif
endfun
call Testinput()
```

I mapped `<C-[>` to `<Esc>` because when multiline appending or inserting, if one presses `<Esc>`, then all the line are updated, however if one press `<C-[>`, then they arent. I tried to fix that inconsistent behaviour with the following mapping to my init.vim:

```
noremap! <C-[> <Esc>
```

However when one tries to abort the above function, it always says "CONTINUE". I remapped `<C-[>`, didnt change `<Esc>`.

Comment: Probably relevant: [How to remove the mapping from `Ctrl-[` to Escape](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24852/18609) and [Disable `<Esc>` but keep `<C-[>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3225/18609).

Comment: Yes probably something to do with that. But how I see it, it's like mapping <Esc> none recursively to <Esc> ... so then the function should still exit as normal?